# Substitute wildcard characters (? and *) in Excel 2010 vba macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Using a macro in Excel 2010, I am trying to replace all "invalid" characters (as defined by a named range) with spaces.

```
Dim sanitisedString As String
    sanitisedString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(uncleanString)
    Dim validCharacters As Range
    Set validCharacters = ActiveWorkbook.Names("ValidCharacters").RefersToRange
    Dim pos As Integer
    For pos = 1 To Len(sanitisedString)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(validCharacters, Mid(sanitisedString, pos, 1)) = 0 Then
            sanitisedString = WorksheetFunction.Replace(sanitisedString, pos, 1, " ")
        End If
    Next
```

It works for all characters except * and ?, because CountIf is interpreting those as wildcard characters.

I have tried escaping all characters in the CountIf, using:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(validCharacters, "~" & Mid(sanitisedString, pos, 1)) = 0
```

but this led to all characters being replaced, regardless of whether they are in the list or not.

I then tried doing two separate Substitute commands, placed after the for loop using "~*" and "~?":

```
sanitisedString = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sanitisedString, "~*", " ")
sanitisedString = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sanitisedString, "~?", " ")
```

but the * and ? still make it through.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are onlyl two wildcards to worry about, you can test for those explicitly:

```
Dim character As String
For pos = 1 To Len(sanitisedString)
    character = Mid(sanitisedString, pos, 1)
    If character = "*" Or character = "?" Then character = "~" & character
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(validCharacters, character) = 0 Then
        Mid$(sanitisedString, pos, 1) = " "
    End If
Next
```